# How to return individual array items from a constructor function

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, constructor

The issue I’m trying to figure out is how to either print the array of options to my HTML as a set or radio buttons; or pass each item from the array `a_options[ ]` individually to radio buttons already present in the HTML.

I understand that `answer1.display(a_option[0]);` yields nothing because `a_option[ ]` is not a variable defined in display.

Any ideas on how to do this or is it possible?

Thanks for the tips and ideas!

```
// My constructor function & class 'Questions'
var Questions = function(q_text)
{
    this.q_text = q_text;
};

// My function for displaying the key-value pair 'q_text' in     'Questions' class.
Questions.prototype.displayQ = function()
{
    return this.q_text;
};

// My newObj created from class 'Questions'.
var question1 = new Questions("Who is the winningest coach at KU?");
// question1 has taken on the protoype of 'q_text'
// Displays the key-value pair 'q_text' where 'q_text' has taken on the value
// passed through the constructor function 'Questions'.
question1.displayQ();



//#######################



// My constructor function & class 'Answers'
var Answers = function(a_options, a_facts, a_img, answer)
{
    this.a_options = a_options;
    this.a_facts = a_facts;
    this.a_img = a_img;
    this.answer = answer;
};

// My function for displaying the key-value pair 'a_options' in 'Answers' class.
Answers.prototype.displayA = function()
{
    return this.a_options;
    // return this.a_facts;
    // return this.a_img;
    // return this.answer;
};

// My newObj created from class 'Answers'
var answer1 = new Answers(['Bill Self', 'Phog Allen', 'Larry Brown', 'James Naismith', 'Roy Williams'], "Bill Self is 372-82 (.822) during his 14 years at the helm of Kansas.", "img/self.jpg", "Bill Self");
// question1 has taken on the protoype of 'a_options'
// Displays the key-value pair 'a_options' where 'a_options' has taken on the value
// passed through the constructor function 'Answers'.
answer1.displayA();
```

Comment: What is `answer1.display()`? The only function you've defined in the `Answer` prototype is `displayA()`.

Comment: You can use `answer1.a_options[0]` to get one of the elements of the `a_options` array.

Comment: `answer1.displayA()` returns this array. You can simply loop through the array, adding them to your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar that is my mistake originally only had `display( )` but with a class for Questions & Answers it was better to have `displayQ( )` & `displayA( )` missed correcting that. Thank you for suggestions and help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Those functions are misnamed. They don't display anything, they just return things. If you want them displayed, that needs to be done by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The issue I’m trying to figure out is how to either print the array of options to my HTML as a set or radio buttons;...*

Your `displayA` method of the `Answers` constructor function is returning the answers as an `array`, so after calling `displayA` you could just loop through the array and create your radio button elements inside the loop and add them to an element, for example.

```
var answers = answer1.displayA();
var answersLen = answers.length
for(var i = 0; i < answersLen; i++) {
  var elem = document.createElement('input');
  elem.type = "radio";
  elem.name = "option";
  elem.value = answers[i];
  elem.id = answers[i];
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

A suggestion would be to change the name of `displayA` to maybe `getOptions`, since `displayA` is not displaying anything and the answers are actually options, since there is only one correct answer to the question if i am not mistaken.

You could as well use the [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to loop through the array and create your radio input elements.

```
answer1.displayA().forEach(function(o) {
  var option = '<br /><input type="radio" name="option" value="'+o+'" id="'+o+'" />'
  + '<lable for"'+o+'">'+o+'</label>';
  document.body.innerHTML += option;
})
```

Another option would be to actually render everything inside the `displayA` method right away and maybe add a form element or pass an element to the method as a container to append your elements to. Maybe like so.

```
Answers.prototype.displayA = function(context, formId) {
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  var facts = document.createElement('p');
  var img = document.createElement('img');

  form.id = formId;
  facts.textContent = this.a_facts;
  img.src =  this.a_img
  form.appendChild(facts);
  form.appendChild(img);

  this.a_options.forEach(function(s) {
    var elem = '<br /><input type="radio" name="option" value="'+s+'" id="'+s+'" />'
    + '<lable for"'+s+'">'+s+'</label>';
    form.innerHTML += elem;
  });

  context.appendChild(form);
};
```

Then you would want to call `displayA` like so

```
answer1.displayA(document.body, "first-question");
```

You could of course pass any element to `displayA` it would not have to be the body.

I am sure you'll get the idea.

Answer (score -3):

```js
//JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) Constructor 
Answers = function (a_options, a_facts, a_img, answer)
{
    this.a_options = a_options;
    this.a_facts = a_facts;
    this.a_img = a_img;
    this.answer = answer;
};

//Prototype adds a property to an already existing JSON Object
Answers.prototype.displayA = function()
{
    return this.a_options;
    // return this.a_facts;
    // return this.a_img;
    // return this.answer;
};


var answer1 = new Answers(['Bill Self', 'Phog Allen', 'Larry Brown', 'James Naismith', 'Roy Williams'], "Bill Self is 372-82 (.822) during his 14 years at the helm of Kansas.", "img/self.jpg", "Bill Self");

//Calling Answers sets variables on answer1. You can do the same in json
answer2 ={
 a_options : ['Bill Self', 'Phog Allen', 'Larry Brown', 'James Naismith', 'Roy Williams'],
 a_facts : "Bill Self is 372-82 (.822) during his 14 years at the helm of Kansas.",
 a_images : "img/self.jpg",
 answer : "Bill Self",
 displayA : function(){
  return this.a_options;
 }
}

output = '';
//You assigned an array to answer1.a_options. So loop through the array. It is possible with and without the DisplayA prototype
for(i=0;i<answer1.a_options.length;i=i+1)
{
 output = output + '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'+answer1.a_options[i]+'">'+answer1.a_options[i]+'<br>';
}

//It is possible to use the displayA prototype too
for(i=0;i<answer1.displayA().length;i=i+1)
{
 output = output + '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'+answer1.displayA()[i]+'">'+answer1.displayA()[i]+'<br>';
}

//It is also possible using the json method 
for(i=0;i<answer2.a_options.length;i=i+1)
{
 output = output + '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'+answer2.a_options[i]+'">'+answer2.a_options[i]+'<br>';
}

for(i=0;i<answer2.displayA().length;i=i+1)
{
 output = output + '<input type="radio" name="name" value="'+answer2.displayA()[i]+'">'+answer2.displayA()[i]+'<br>';
}

document.write(output);
```